# SQL calculations between specific cells in single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table that looks like this below:
[image: My table]

I would like to run a calculation where I return all the cells where some calculations are true.

For instance, I would run something like:

```
Select group, alonecombo, statistic
where tablenumber = "B3002" 
AND geoname = "Alabama"
FROM table1
```

I need to add a condition like: WHERE totalpop > 100000 (the statistic value of total pop)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'AND totalpop > 100000' ?  Does just adding the condition to the `where` clause do what you want?

Comment: or just `group = 'totalpop' AND statistic > 100000` since they are two different columns.

Comment: Note that `group` is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add another condition to your where clause:

```
Select group, alonecombo, statistic
where 
    tablenumber = "B3002" 
    AND geoname = "Alabama"
    and (group = "totalpop" and statistic > 100000)
FROM table1
```